# Find $f(f(f(f(f(f(\cdots f(x)))))))$ $2018$ times

Tags: functions, recurrence-relations

> I was given a problem to calculate $f(f(f(\dots f(x))))$ $2018$ times if $f(x)=\frac{x}{3} + 3$ and $x=4$.

Is it even possible to be done without a computer?

Comment: I'd first look at what happens when you iterate this several times, for small values of "several", and see if there's a pattern. Then try to prove by mathtematical induction that the pattern persists.

Comment: Hint: $f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{x}{3^n}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{3^{n-(k+2)}}$.

Comment: The second term is a geometric series.

Comment: As a worshipper of simplicity, I find that among seven answers posted so far, mine is the simplest. That's what I usually try to do. (But maybe not everyone will agree.....)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can rewrite the problem as a first-order difference equation:
\begin{align*}
    a_{n+1} &= \frac{1}{3} a_n + 3 \\ a_0 &= 4
\end{align*}
We want to know $a_{2018}$.

There are a number of standard techniques to solve these, that are covered in discrete math courses.  One trick is temporarily ignore the $+3$ at the end and find a general solution to $a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{3} a_{n}$.  It's not too hard to see that $a_{n} = \frac{1}{3^n}$ satisfies that, and so does any multiple of it.

OK, now what about the $3$?  Let's look for a constant solution to $a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{3}a_n  + 3$.  That is, we solve $a = \frac{1}{3}a + 3 $ for $a$.  We get $a = \frac{9}{2}$.

Combining the two, we have a solution $$a_n = c \cdot \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n + \frac{9}{2}$$
This sequence does satisfy $a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{3}a_n + 3$ for any $c$, as you can check.  We now just need to fit the initial condition $a_0 = 4$.  Substituting $n=0$ gives
$$
    4= c \cdot 1 + \frac{9}{2} \implies c = - \frac{1}{2}
$$
So our particular solution is 
$$
a_n = -\frac{1}{2} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n + \frac{9}{2}
    = \frac{9}{2} - \frac{1}{2\cdot 3^n}
$$
Therefore
$$
    a_{2018} = \frac{9}{2} - \frac{1}{2\cdot 3^{2018}}
$$
This is very, *[very](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=9%2F2%20-%201%2F(2*3%5E2018))* close to $\frac{9}{2} = 4.5$.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Consider the following recurrence relationship
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{3}+3$$
for $n=0,1,\cdots$, and $a_0=4$. Now compute $a_n$ in terms of $n$.

---

If you are unaware of the method for solving linear recurrence relationships then consider
$b_n=a_{n}-\frac{9}{2}$ and observe that
$$b_{n+1}=\frac{b_{n}}{3} \implies b_{n}=\frac{b_0}{3^n} \implies a_n=\frac{9}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3^n}.$$

Answer (score 4):

You have $f(x) = \frac 1 3 x + 3.$ The numbers $f(x)$ and $f(w)$ will always be at a distance from each other that is $1/3$ the distance between $x$ and $w.$ That implies the sequence $f(x), f(f(x)), f(f(f(x))), \ldots$ converges to a point $x_0$ satisfying $f(x_0) = x_0.$ So we have
$$
\frac 1 3 x_0 + 3 = x_0
$$
and therefore
$$
x_0 = \frac 9 2.
$$
Since $f(9/2) = 9/2,$ the distance between $f(x)$ and $9/2$ is $1/3$ the distance between $x$ and $9/2.$ Then ask how many times you need to multiply by $1/3.$

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to spot a pattern.

$$f(x)=3+\frac x3=\frac13(3^2+x)$$ $$f(f(x))=f\left(\frac13(9+x)\right)=3+\frac{9+x}{9}=4+\frac x9=\frac1{3^2}(3^3+3^2+x)$$ $$f(f(f(x)))=f\left(\frac19(36+x)\right)=3+\frac{36+x}{27}=\frac{13}3+\frac x{27}=\frac1{3^3}(3^4+3^3+3^2+x)$$

So iterating $2018$ times, we have $$f(f(f(\cdots f(x))))=\frac1{3^{2018}}(3^{2019}+3^{2018}+...+3^2+x)$$ or $$3^1+3^0+3^{-1}+...+3^{-2016}+\frac x{3^{2018}}\approx 4.5+\frac{2018}{3^{2018}}$$ Now since $3^{2018}$ is much bigger than $2018$, that term could be negligible so we can conclude that $$\boxed{f(f(f(\cdots f(x))))=4.5}$$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there exists an $x$ such that $f(x) = x$

$f(x) = \frac {x}{3} + 3 = x\\
x = \frac 92$

It would be a reasonable guess that we get something very close to $\frac {9}{2}$

$f(4) = 4 +\frac 13\\
f(4+ \frac 13) = 4 + \frac 13 + \frac 19\\
f(4+ \frac 13 + \frac 19) = 4 + \frac 13 + \frac 19 + \frac 1{27}$

Now we are on to something.

$f(4+ \sum_\limits{i=1}^{n} (\frac {1}{3})^i) = \frac {4}{3} + \frac{1}3\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n} (\frac {1}{3})^i + 3 =
4 + \sum_\limits{i=1}^{n+1}(\frac{1}3)^i$

$4 +\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n} \frac {1}{3}^n = 4 + \frac {(1-(\frac 13)^n)}{2}\\
4 +\sum_\limits{i=1}^{2018} \frac {1}{3}^n = 4 + \frac {(1-(\frac 13)^{2018})}{2}\\
4\frac 12 - \frac 12(\frac 13)^{2018}$

Answer (score 2):

Consider that for all $x$ we have $$3f(f(x))-f(x)=\frac{x+36}{3}-\frac{x+9}{3}=9$$
From this putting $x=f(x)$ we get
$$3f(f(f(x)))-f(f(x))=9$$
I'll write $f^n(x)=\underbrace{f(f(\cdots f(x))\cdots )}_n$ from now
$$3f^3(x)-f^2(x)=9\\9f^3(x)-3f^2(x)=27$$
Also putting $x=f^2(x)$ $$3f^4(x)-f^3(x)=9\\27f^4(x)-9f^{3}(x)=81$$
And in general $$3^{n-1}f^n(x)-3^{n-2}f^{n-1}(x)=3^n$$
Now lets sum this from $n=2018$ to $n=2$
$$3^{2017}f^{2018}(x)-3^{2016}f^{2017}(x)+3^{2016}f^{2017}(x)-3^{2015}f^{2016}(x)+3^{2015}f^{2016}(x)-\cdots-f(x)=9+27+81+\cdots+3^{2018}\\$$
We can see that most of the terms cancel and we get
$$3^{2017}f^{2018}(x)-f(x)=9+27+\cdots +3^{2018}$$
You can recognize the RHS as the geometric sequence and you know what $f(x)$ is, so you can finish yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Well, *maybe* we will be able to find that iterating the function $n$ times yields so function in terms of $n$.

Notation:  Let $f^n(x)$ be defined as $f(f(f(..... f(x)))...)$ iterated $n$ times.

$f(x) = \frac x3 + 3$

$f^2(x) = \frac x9 + 1 + 3 = \frac x9 + 4$.

$f^3(x) = \frac x{27} + 1\frac 13 + 3 = \frac x{3^3} + \frac {13}3$

$f^4(x) = \frac x{3^4} + \frac {13}{9} + 3 = \frac x{3^4} + \frac {40}{9}$

Any patterns?  Clearly the first term is $\frac x{3^n}$ but what is the pattern of the second term $3, 4, \frac {13}3, \frac {40}{9}$.  I can see how then denominator is $3^{n-2}$ (and it's pretty obvious why the happens).  And the numerators are $1,4,13,40$ which are $1, 3+1, 3(3+1) + 1, 3(3(3+1)+1)+1$ which if we expand them are $1, 3+1, 3^2 + 3 + 1, 3^3 + 3^2 + 3 + 1$.

Further more:  $x^n + x^{n-1} + ..... + 1 = \frac {x^{n+1} - 1}{x - 1}$.

So $1,4,13, 40 = \frac {3-1}2, \frac {3^2 -1} 2, \frac {3^3-1}2, \frac {3^4-1}2$.

So.

$f(x) = \frac x3 + \frac {3-1}{2*3^{-1}}$

$f^2(x) = \frac x{3^2} + \frac {3^2 -1} {2*3^0}$

$f^3(x) = \frac x{3^3} + \frac {3^3 -1} {2*3^1}$

$f^4(x) = \frac x{3^4} + \frac {3^4 -1}{2*3^2}$.

And we can claim:

$f^n(x) = \frac x{3^n} + \frac {3^n -1} {2*3^{n-2}}$.

And we can prove it via induction.

$f^{n+ 1}= \frac {f^n(x)}3 + 3 = \frac {\frac x{3^n} + \frac {3^n -1} {2*3^{n-2}}}3 + 3$

$= \frac x{3^{n+1}} +  \frac {3^n -1} {2*3^{n-1}}+ \frac {2*3^n}{2*3^{n-1}}$

$= \frac x{3^{n+1}} +  \frac {3^n+2*3^n -1} {2*3^{n-1}}$

$= \frac x{3^{n+1}} +  \frac {3*3^n -1} {2*3^{n-1}}$

$= \frac x{3^{n+1}} +  \frac {3^{n+1} -1} {2*3^{n-1}}$

So we have

$f^{2018}(4)  = \frac 4{3^{2018}} + \frac {3^{2018} -1} {2*3^{2016}}$

$\frac {4*2 + 9*3^{2018}-9}{2*3^{2018}}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_{n+1} =f(x_n)$ that is  $x_{n+1} =\frac{x_n}{3}+3 $

Letting $$u_n =x_n -\frac{3}{2}\implies u_{n+1}=\frac13 u_n \implies u_n = \frac{u_1}{3^{n-1}} \implies x_n = \frac{3}{2}+\frac{x_1 -\frac{3}{2}}{3^{n-1}}$$

Hence, we have $$ \color{blue}{ \underbrace{f(f(f(f(f(f(\cdots f(x)))))))}_{n~~times} = x_n = \frac{3}{2}+\frac{2x -3}{2\cdot3^{n-1}}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f^{(n)}(x)=\dfrac{x}{3^n}+\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{1}{3^{n-(k+2)}}$.The second term is straightforward to compute.

Answer (score 1):

if $f(x)=\frac{x}{3}+3$

Then $f^2(x)=\frac{f(x)}{3}+3=\frac{x}{9}+\frac{3}{3}+3$

and $f^3(x)=\frac{f^2(x)}{3}+4=\frac{x}{27}+\frac{3}{9}+\frac{3}{3}+3$

By induction the general form is emerging as:

$$f^n(x)=3^{-n}x+3\left(\sum_{k=1}^n3^{1-k}\right)$$

Use the formula for a geometric sum and plug in $x=4, n=2018$:

$f^{2018}(4)=4+\frac{1}{2}\left(1-3^{-2018}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look too bad to be honest.
We have:

$$f(x)=\frac{x}3+3=\frac{x+9}{3}$$
$$f^2(x)=\frac{\frac{x+9}{3}+9}{3}=\frac{x+\overbrace{36}^{(3+1)\cdot9}}{9}$$
$$f^4(x)=\frac{\frac{x+36}{9}+36}{9}=\frac{x+\overbrace{360}^{(9+1)\cdot36}}{81}$$
$$f^8(x)=\frac{\frac{x+360}{81}+360}{81}=\frac{x+(81+1)\cdot360}{81^2}$$

Can you see the pattern? Do you think you can take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this, let's first write something down

$f(4) = 13/3 = (4 + 9)/3 = (1 + 3 + 9)/3$

$f(f(4)) = 40/9 = (13 + 27)/9 = (4 + 9 + 27) = (1 + 3 + 9 + 27)/9$

$f(f(f(4))) = 121/27 = (40 + 81)/27 = (1 + 3 + 9 + 27 + 81)/27$

We observe a rule:

1) Denominator:

It's the previous denominator  $\times 3$ because we basically take the previous number and divide it by $3$ and add $3$ to it.

2) Numerator:

The numerator is the sum of a geometric progression, the last number being $3^{n + 1}$, where $n$ is the number of times we did: $f(f(...f(x)))$. In this case, the last number will be $3^{2019}$.

I hope this helped!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please format your answers using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)